# Why does it only Insert the root? (AVL Tree) [C]

Tags: c, malloc, avl-tree

EDIT: Previous problem solved. I have problems with my Insert function for my AVL Tree. Im sitting on this for so long now.. I really hope somebody will read this, I didnt want to create a new Thread

The function:

```
void AVL_insert_value(AVLTree* avlt, int value)
{

AVLNode* next=avlt->root;
AVLNode* current;

if (avlt->root==NULL){
        avlt->root=CreateNode(value);
        }
else {

        while(next!=NULL)
                {
                current=next;
                if(value < next->value) {
                        next=current->left;
                        }

                else if (value > next->value) {
                     next=current->right;
                        }
                else{
                        return;
                }

            if((value > current->value) && current->right==NULL) { current->right=CreateNode(value); }
            if((value < current->value) && current->left==NULL)  { current->left=CreateNode(value); }
        }
    }
}
```

All the structs are typdef'd, CreateNode:

```
AVLNode* CreateNode(int value) {

AVLNode* newNode=malloc(sizeof(AVLNode));
newNode->left=newNode->right=NULL;
newNode->value=value;
newNode->height=1;
return newNode;
}
```

No Errors, No warnings, valgrind doesnt complain (even with --leak-check=full), no matter what I do, only the root is inserted.. where do I lose the other ones? What am I doing wrong? would appreciate any kind of help..

Comment: you cannot free it here. Free it when you remove the node from the list, not before... but since it's returned, you have the pointer so you can free it after the function call, even if it's another pointer variable name..

Comment: Yes thats what I wanted, but Valgrind does not like that malloc..

Comment: maybe you should elaborate around your function to show a [mcve]: (read: not a _wall of code_) and the corresponding valgrind output. Then we'll be able to help you. Your routine looks OK.

Comment: Was already copying it in, there it is! Thanks alot for helping

Comment: `FreeTree` and `CreateNode` look OK, but are created nodes actually inserted correctly in the tree (such that FreeTree can ever reach them)? I think you should consult your debugger. BTW: Do you have to free `avlt` as well?

Comment: @ykykyk There's no problem with that `malloc`, valgrind is telling you where the lost memory was allocated. Somewhere you allocated a node and didn't free it. Stephan is right, it's probably `avlt`.